# Can you use open source sample rate converters like soxr to manage frequency error between two audio clocks?

Tags: c++, audio

If you have an audio stream, and the source is using a different sampling rate than the destination, then sample rate conversion is necessary.  I can set source to a nominal 48000 and destination to a nominal 96000 and employ something like a libsoxr converter between them, setup with those nominal sampling rates.  But, if the source is actually 48002.657 when measured on average, and the destination is some other specific non-whole-number frequency, then I'm finding that soxr crashes and won't accept those rates.  The documentation does say it converts both rational and irrational sampling rate ratios (?).

So, am I asking too much to expect an open source library to convert fractional sampling rates?  Could it also be used to correct ONLY frequency error, i.e. could it convert 48003.687 to 47999.9654 (adding/removing a sample every once in a while as the stream continues operation)?

The usage scenario is a typical real time audio stream.  Chunks of samples (ex: 64, 128, or 512) are arriving at the source sample rate and chunks of samples are being removed at the destination sample rate.  There is a small queue employed in the stream.  If the sample rate converter can handle the frequency error, then the queue size should not grow or shrink over time and therefore can be made smaller, reducing the latency of the stream (this is the overall goal).

Comment: are you sending digital information over this analog audio channel ?   if not and you are sending analog information then I suggest you ignore these non standard sampling rate differences and adhere to the standard sample rates ... if the data is for human consumption then the distortion incurred will not be audible ...  48000 / 48002.657 equates to 0.99994464889 accuracy ... so the answer is YES just treat 48002.657  as 48000 and use the open source utils ... this reminds me of the distinction between precision and accuracy

Comment: The issue is not about the audio fidelity, but rather a queue size problem.  The actual flow is source->conv(soxr)->queue->dest.  So, a nominal example source[48]->conv->[96]->queue->dest[96].  But really what is going on is source[48003.657]->conv->[96007.314]->queue->dest[95999.632].  Those differing SR's going in/out of the queue will cause it to fill/deplete over time - enough to where it is an issue within a typical song length of 4min.  So, if the conv could output something much closer to 95999.632, then it would eliminate the problem.

Comment: is this an academic exercise or are you encountering clocks in the wild this far off ?

Comment: This is an actual case.  The source clock comes from a standard Macbook Pro internal audio.  The destination clock is an Antelope Audio Orion 32.  The numbers I'm providing are just examples.  Based on some preliminary measurements, I think I'm seeing this magnitude of error...but I do know for sure that whatever the numbers are, they are off enough to cause queue problems over a 4 minutes period.

Comment: One other note:  if I use an Apogee Duet as the source clock, there is no problem (i.e. both duet and orion are accurate, and the Macbook is not).  But I need to handle a variety of sound cards - accurate and not so accurate.

Comment: typically there is an agreement of buffer size between both publish and subscribe sides of any streaming media channel ... if you did achieve your desired sample rate conversion it would introduce the need for your ecosystem to handle a variable size buffer ... anticipate this in the event you get your conversions to work ... if you can park some of your audio as link(s) we can try to help to resample

Comment: I was able to get soxr to handle fractional sample rates with it's default quality settings.  So, if I can accurately measure the source and destination sample rates (a separate problem), then I can manage the stream and have a fairly constant queue.  Thanks for your help.